# is there a way to peer/connect lightsail vpc with aws vpc on same region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail, aws-vpc-peering

I m studying the below link to connect lightsail vpc with aws vpc but it is connecting to default one as mentioned in document. Resources i m trying to use is in another vpc.
https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-set-up-vpc-peering-with-aws-resources

Is there any other way we can connect lightsail vpc and aws vpc manually or some other way instead of using default one.

Comment: Mmm. The documentation seems to suggest that it only works with the Default VPC. The UI doesn't even offer a choice of VPCs.

Comment: yeah @JohnRotenstein there is simple check box if i click on it, it will only enable vpc peering for default one. I was looking for work around since transitivity is not supported. I dont have any idea how to make this one work.

Comment: Suppose I have 3 light sail instances (also knows as vps - virtual private server), then, can they by default talk to each other? If yes, then what exactly does enabling the VPC peering checkmark in the region, under accounts section do?